# Cassandra ReBuild

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-enterprise

DSE Version 4.8.2

I added 6 new nodes to a cluster with data and put bootstrap:false.  After they joined, I am running a rebuild on each.  I believe 1 NODE is done but the command at the console is still "running" (For example, I cannot run another command yet).  I want to make sure its fully done.  There is no compaction and no streams active to that unit.  UPDATE : It has now been 4 days and still sitting at the command prompt.

Is there anything other than compationstats and netstats that maybe I am missing?  I saw it stream the data, then it compacted it but now.....

One more question, after I am fully finished rebuilds then cleanups is there any other tasks I should consider to fully sync the cluster?

UPDATE :

As I am trying to run a rebuild I keep getting the following error.  I upped my file limit in Ubuntu 14.04 to 200,000 and I still get the error.

> INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:747] 2016-02-29 03:57:18,114 
>   Memtable.java:382 - Completed flushing
>   /media/slot02/cjd/match-b633b251a04f11e58b7b89a485a622c1/cjd-match-tmp-ka-127932-Data.db
>   (71.866MiB) for commitlog position
>   ReplayPosition(segmentId=1456708497054, position=14141564) INFO 
>   [ScheduledTasks:1] 2016-02-29 03:58:33,573  ColumnFamilyStore.java:905
>   - Enqueuing flush of compaction_history: 17177 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:748] 2016-02-29 03:58:33,574 
>   Memtable.java:347 - Writing
>   Memtable-compaction_history@971836863(3.428KiB serialized bytes, 123
>   ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit) INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:748]
>   2016-02-29 03:58:33,575  Memtable.java:382 - Completed flushing
>   /media/slot01/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/system-compaction_history-tmp-ka-142-Data.db
>   (0.000KiB) for commitlog position
>   ReplayPosition(segmentId=1456708497058, position=20942643) WARN 
>   [STREAM-IN-/10.0.1.243] 2016-02-29 04:00:02,317  CLibrary.java:231 -
>   open(/media/slot01/cjd/match-b633b251a04f11e58b7b89a485a622c1,
>   O_RDONLY) failed, errno (24). ERROR [STREAM-IN-/10.0.1.243] 2016-02-29
>   04:00:02,541  JVMStabilityInspector.java:117 - JVM state determined to
>   be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /media/slot01/cjd/match-b633b251a04f11e58b7b89a485a622c1/cjd-match-tmp-ka-128371-Index.db
>   (Too many open files)     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]    at
>   java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_72]    at
>   java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_72]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.(SequentialWriter.java:78)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:111)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:106)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter$IndexWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:587)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:140)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.(SSTableWriter.java:81)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReader.createWriter(StreamReader.java:135)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamReader.read(CompressedStreamReader.java:80)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingFileMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingFileMessage.java:48)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingFileMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingFileMessage.java:38)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:56)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:250)
>   ~[cassandra-all-2.1.11.908.jar:2.1.11.908]    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72] INFO  [Thread-2]
>   2016-02-29 04:00:02,543  DseDaemon.java:418 - DSE shutting down...

My OpenFile Limit is currently 200,000 from ulimit -a.  I could try to go higher, but Cassandra suggests a 100,000 limit.

If I had to GUESS, the issue is one node cant compact due to 2 disks being full on a node where the data is coming from.   As it pulls the rebuild data from there, its pulling 50,000 small files unlike other nodes pulling 1-2 larger files.  Maybe that is what I have to fix first?

Really need help...  Thanks!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I added 6 new nodes to a cluster with data and put bootstrap:false

First, this is wrong, according to the documentation, when adding a new node to a cluster, you should put `auto_bootstrap = true`

See here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html

Second, it is recommended to add nodes one by one or two nodes at a time, not all 6 nodes at the same time because it will put a lot of pressure on the network (because of data streaming)

Comment: doanduyhai,  While I totally agree with your statement.  I had nemerous issues when joining the cluster with auto_bootstrap:true.  In other articles I read, they said set to false, rebuild then once it completes set to true.  Every time I tried to join I would get java-heap-out errors.  Each NODE has 16 Cores and 40GB of RAM.  Should I re-attempt to set to true and rejoin now?  Some data has been added to the new nodes though already.

Comment: Did you add nodes ONE BY ONE or all 6 nodes at the same time ?

Comment: I added them all at the same time (or 3, then 3).  Currently, I am running a cleanup on CASS4 node which has two filled drives.  We do run replication=2 so hopefully that means that it will pull that data from another node, if not, no harm to foul.  Is it critical that nodes be added one at a time?

Comment: You should only do CLEAN UP once the streaming of data is finished correctly otherwise you risk loosing data. We recommend to add nodes one by one or 2 by 2 because it has a great impact on existing node (data streaming = reading data on disk + stream them on the network)

Comment: What about the error message listed above?  I think there is some type of memory leak.

Comment: ERROR [STREAM-IN-/10.0.1.243] 2016-02-29 04:00:02,541 JVMStabilityInspector.java:117 - JVM state determined to be unstable. Exiting forcefully due to: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /media/slot01/cjd/match-b633b251a04f11e58b7b89a485a622c1/cjd-match-tmp-ka-128371-Index.db (Too many open files) at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)  --> Too many opened files.If you get this error wth 200000 ulimit, it means that there are too many small SSTables. Probably compaction does not keep up

Comment: Can you please count the number of files with pattern *Data.db in the data folder  /media/slot01/cjd/match-b633b251a04f11e58b7b89a485a622c1/ ?

Comment: I couldnt get a count, but I can tell you the amount is insane.  I just a basic ls /media/.... and it spammed for like 3 minutes.  Odd part is, media/slot01 isnt the full drive, it has like 2TB.  I think maybe the compaction was attempting on the other two full drives, but was stuck because of the drive full.  Which now when I check "Compaction Waiting" there is like 1700~ waiting.  Is there a way to say, "only compact this data drive?" or is there a way to clear some data off another drive to allow the compaction?  In attempt to clear space on the one drive I am running a cleanup.

Comment: I also just checked other nodes and there is maybe 4-5 Data files per folder.  It seems only this one node seems corrupted.  What would you suggest?  Keep the cleanup?  Run a manual compaction command?

Comment: So the root cause of all this is *compaction not keeping up*. First resolve this issue before moving on ... Which hardware do you have ? What kind of disk ? SSDs ? Spinning disk ?

Comment: Doanduyahi,  I think the issue is more or less issue with corrupted SSTables I had way back.  I thought I could just change to best_effort then run a repair.  I never actually deleted the corrupted tables.  I did scrub but I didnt know it doesnt do the delete itself.  I think im just go to purge the node of data, restart and rebuild.  I am running rebuild on all other new nodes now with CASS4 off.  I have 10 of the same servers, all storing the same data and compaction keeps up on them no problem.  I appreciate your help, it did lead me to the a "possible" answer.

Comment: So far all rebuilds havent crashed since I took NODE4 out.  Once the entire array is rebuilt, I will clear NODE4 out and rebuild that one.  For us, data loss isn't huge, (OF course no one wants it) so even if a few rows are lost were OK with that.  Once I have the rebuilds done, and I run a cleanup I should see (After the cleanup) the first set of nodes total space should go down to about the same as the other nodes, correct?

Comment: Yes, "nodetool clean up" remove data that no longer below to the current node token ranges. Usually you execute "nodetool clean up" after a cluster scale out.

Comment: One more question.  We had 1 Node go down during another machine is rebuilding.  It required data to come from that node.  The crashed node is back up, but its still at the same bytes (nodetool netstats).  How should I proceed?  Wait for the rebuild to finish then re-run a rebuild?  Can I stop the rebuild and restart it and not require it to re-download all the data it already got?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your ulimit is properly set

```
cat /proc/<DSE pid>/limits
```

Often I see folks that thought they set ulimit config but did it for the wrong user. If you check for the specific process id you can he 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

One tricky thing is that whatever you will set via limits.conf will be overwritten by the settings from limits.d/cassandra.conf so keep in mind to edit also the file from there according to your needs.

Also, as @phact mentioned, make sure what you expect really exists via the above cat.